# AES CBC mode in C

Tags: c, aes

I am trying to cipher and decipher in AES CBC mode, but I have errors.

My code:

```
BYTE initVec[16] = {0x00};
BYTE message[16];
BYTE cipher[16];

for(r = 0; r < 16; r++){
    int read2 =  fread(cipher, 1, 16, fpIn); // Read last block
    aes_decrypt(buffer, cipher, key); // Decrypt - buffer
    buffer[r] = buffer[r] ^ cipher[r];
}
```

After the first block, I need to XOR the previous block of ciphertext with the current block of decrypted data for other blocks. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you signed the [Foot-Shooting Agreement](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html)?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a pointer for `initVec`. Initially, it points to the initial vector. Then after each iteration, change the pointer to reference the ciphertext of the previous round. CBC means essentially that the ciphertext of each block serves as the initial vector for the next block. The first block has no previous block, and so a special block is present: **the** initial vector.

In fact, looking at some code, this is exactly how I did it back in 2001 when AES was new and I wanted to [make my own](http://www.kylheku.com/~kaz/rijndael.html):

Encrypt:

```
void 
rijn_cbc_encrypt(rijn_keysched_t *sched, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *out, 
    const unsigned char *in, size_t nblocks)
{
    unsigned char *ivec = iv;
    size_t blocksize = numrows_to_blocksize(sched->rijn_param.rijn_blockrows);
    size_t i, nbytes = nblocks * blocksize;

    for (i = 0; i < nbytes; i += blocksize) {
        xor_mem(out + i, in + i, ivec, blocksize);
        rijn_encrypt(sched, out + i, out + i);
        ivec = out + i;   /* <---- next block's ivec is this block's output! */
    }

    memcpy(iv, ivec, blocksize);
}
```

Decrypt. Here, we create an `ivec` point at the top of each iteration to point to the previous input (ciphertext) block when `i > 0`. For the first iteration, `i == 0`, we point it to `iv`. Very simple!

**Note that the decryption marches backwards through the data!**

```
void 
rijn_cbc_decrypt(rijn_keysched_t *sched, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *out,
    const unsigned char *in, size_t nblocks)
{
    rijn_block_t iv_save;
    size_t blocksize = numrows_to_blocksize(sched->rijn_param.rijn_blockrows);
    size_t i, nbytes = nblocks * blocksize;

    if (nblocks > 0) {
        memcpy(&iv_save, in + nbytes - blocksize, blocksize);

        for (i = nbytes - blocksize; i < nbytes; i -= blocksize) {
            const unsigned char *ivec = (i > 0) ? in + i - blocksize : iv;
            rijn_decrypt(sched, out + i, in + i);
            xor_mem(out + i, out + i, ivec, blocksize);
        }

        memcpy(iv, &iv_save, blocksize);
    }
}
```